# SectionsPagerAdapter - No view found for id for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a App with a Slidingmenu where i can pick different Fragment, which displays different kind of ListFragments.

The ListFragments will be filled by JSON from my Database Server.
If you Click on one of the Listitems, a new Fragment is shown which contains more Details about the selected Listitem.

```
public void updateList(final Activity a, final ListFragment L) {

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(a, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_comment, new String[] {TAG_PIC_ID,TAG_CATEGORY, TAG_ACTIVITY, TAG_DATUM, TAG_AKTUSR, TAG_MAXUSR, TAG_GENDER, /*TAG_POST_ID,*/ TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                    TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.imgrow, R.id.category, R.id.activity/*R.id.id*/ , R.id.datum, R.id.aktusr, R.id.maxusr, R.id.gender, /*R.id.category,*/ R.id.title, R.id.message,
                    R.id.username });

    L.setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = L.getListView();  

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            int intid = (int)id;


            Details nextFrag= new Details();
            L.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, nextFrag, "Test")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        }


    });
}
```

When i call the function from a "single" fragment its no problem and the DetailPage is shown.

The Problem is when i call the function from a TabbedActivity with a SectionsPagerAdapter.

The TabbedActivity

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

public class TabbedActivity extends Fragment {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

public static final String TAG = TabbedActivity.class.getSimpleName();

ViewPager mViewPager;


public static TabbedActivity newInstance() {
    return new TabbedActivity();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_one, container, false);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getChildFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    return v;
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        Fragment fragment = new newEntrys();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new newEntrys();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new oldEntrys();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Aktuelle Einträge";
        case 1:
            return "Vergangene Einträge";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

The TabbedActivity contains the 2 Fragments newEntry and oldEntry which are nearly equal.

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu.fragments;



public class RegisterdEvents_new extends ListFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.read, container, false);


    return rootView;
}

public void startTask(){

    Read SO = new Read();


    Load LEvt = SO.new Load(getActivity(), this, "NEW");
    LEvt.execute();





}

public void onResume() {
    startTask();
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

So the function updateList above is called in 
Load LEvt = SO.new Load(getActivity(), this, "NEW");

But the problem is that i always get the Error

```
No view found for id 0x7f0a000f (package:id/frame_container) for fragment Details{e3992e2 #0 id=0x7f0a000f Test}
```

Someone of you can help me to solve this problem?